# PHP file_exists() to check multiple files at once

Tags: php, file-exists

I want to check multiple files at once if they exist or not. I want to show a text if any of these files exists:

```
$filepre = ''.$br.'/filethumb/'.$name.'.jpg';
$filess = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'.jpg';
$filess1 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'1.jpg';
$filess2 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'2.jpg';
$filess3 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'3.jpg';
$filess4 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'4.jpg';
$filess5 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'5.jpg';
$filess6 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'6.jpg';
$filess7 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'7.jpg';
$filess8 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'8.jpg';
$filess9 = ''.$br.'/ss/'.$name.'9.jpg';
```

Then I want to check if any of these files exist or not. If 1 of these 10 files exists then show a text `"Screenshots:"`. If no file exists then nothing will be shown.

I tried:

```
if (file_exists($filess or $filess1 or $filess2 or $filess3 or $filess4 or $filess5 or $filess6 or $filess7 or $filess8 or $filess9)){
echo 'Screenshots';
}
```

Did I do anything wrong that it's not working?

Comment: Put your filenames in an array and loop through it.

Comment: how? can you help me in this by write down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rearrange the checking in the `if` condition,

```
if (file_exists($filess) or file_exists($filess1) or file_exists($filess2) or file_exists($filess3) or file_exists($filess4) or file_exists($filess5) or file_exists($filess6) or file_exists($filess7) or file_exists($filess8) or file_exists($filess9)){
    echo 'Screenshots';
}
```

Only if you don't want to use array and looping.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that is what i am looking for and its working.

Answer (score 6):

Put your filenames in an array and loop through:

```
$files = array('file_name_1', 'file_name_2'...);

foreach($files as $file){
    if(file_exists($file)){
        echo "screenshots";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use an array, filter it and check if it is empty or not:

```
$files[] = $br.'/ss/'.$name.'1.jpg';
$files[] = $br.'/ss/'.$name.'2.jpg';
//etc...

if(array_filter($files, 'file_exists')) {
    echo "Screenshots:";
}
```

This is extendable as you can compare the `count()` of the result to see if 2, 3, 4, etc.. exist or if the count equals the count of the original array.